# Error while downloading MODIS data using runGDAL

Tags: r, modis

I am new to GIS and spatial analysis. I am trying to download MODIS vegetation index data using runGDAL from the ‘MODIS’ version 1.1.5 package (https://rdocumentation.org/packages/MODIS/versions/1.2.3).
This is my code:

```
ext<- getTile(tileH = 25,tileV = 7)

runGdal( "MOD13A2",collection = "061", begin = "2015.01.01", end = "2015.12.31", extent = ext, job = "2015", SDSstring = "101")
```

Earlier when I ran it for years 2016-2018, it ran perfectly fine. Now when I run the same code it gives me the following:

```
outProj          =  asIn 
pixelSize        =  asIn 
resamplingType   =  near 
Output Directory =  C:/Users/Aparna/Desktop/IISC/Data/USGS-NDVI-MOD13A3_v6/MOD13A2-NDVI-2015-India-tileH25-tileV7-R-code/2015 
########################
Local structure is up-to-date. Using offline information!
Error in dirs[ids] : invalid subscript type 'list'
```

I tried the code with other products and collections and for a single file as well instead of the whole year and I get the same error.
I am unsure as to what this error means.

Comment: There's no package called "MODIS" on CRAN. Can you edit your Q and detail where you got it from so we can figure this out? And if possible make your code into a reproducible example we can cut and paste - as it stands even if we had your MODIS package we still don't know what your `th` and `tv` are.

Comment: I have edited the question with the tile information. However, the package is called MODIS itself. I have added a link to the R documentation for the package.

Comment: A version dated 2020 was the last recorded version in the CRAN archive before it was removed. Are you using a CRAN version or the latest github version?

Comment: When you say "earlier" it worked for 2016-2018, how earlier? Earlier today? Or weeks/months/years ago? Does it still work for those years? Are you sure there's actually data for 2015?

Comment: I am using the github version (https://github.com/MatMatt/MODIS). Earlier as in a week ago.

Comment: It is working now (a day later). However, if you could explain the error message I got previously, it would be really helpful.